# Sorting an NSDictionary keys

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I create a dictionary with this data:

```
NSString *fileContentMap = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:MapPath];  

SBJsonParser *parserMap = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dataMap = (NSDictionary *) [parserMap objectWithString:fileContentMap error:nil];

NSArray *MaparrayLongitude = [dataMap objectForKey:@"longitude"];
NSArray *MaparrayLatitude = [dataMap objectForKey:@"latitude"];


NSDictionary* DictionaryMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:MaparrayLatitude forKeys:MaparrayLongitude];
```

..then I read it with this code:

```
 NSArray *allKeys2 = [DictionaryMap allKeys];

    NSString *key2 = [allKeys2 objectAtIndex:i];
    NSObject *obj2 = [DictionaryMap objectForKey:key2];
```

...but the keys are not ordered, and I want them to be ordered in the original order. How can I do this??